# Catalan Numbers and Gambling

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence, summation, catalan-numbers

Working on a random walk gambling problem, $a_n$ denotes a certain probability that a player wins a prize where the coin is fair. Variable $n$ denotes the number of the coin flip, and the probability of winning on an individual coin flip is $1/2$, and losing is also $1/2$. 
 Now, I have computed the correct individual probabilities as the following: $a_{2n} =\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}(1/2)^{2n}$.

The problem is, I need the *sum* of **all** these probabilities, because I need the probability of winning **in the general case for all $n$**, $n$ to $\infty$. I have no clue how to proceed. The Catalan numbers expand exponentially, but the $(1/2)^{2n}$ decays exponentially.

Answer (score 2):

The generating function for Catalan numbers is
$$C(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x},$$ this comes from the relation $c(x)=1+xc(x)^2.$ 
Notice that $x=1/4$ gives what you want.

Comment: While I understand how that is equal to the generating function, I do not know how this helps me in calculating the above total sum.

Comment: @ViolettaBlejder $a_{2n}=C_n*(1/4)^n$

Comment: @Phicar You arrived first! (+1)

Comment: @Phicar Right, I see that, but what you gave me is a simplified version of the above. I'm lost when it comes to calculating the overall sum for all **n**. **2** is theoretically wrong, because the sum of all the probabilities cannot be more than 1. It's baffling.

Comment: @ViolettaBlejder The problem statement is not clear to check where the catalan numbers appear. Perhaps you can give us more details? Also, just from what you wrote, do you really want $n=0$? Perhaps no.

Comment: @Phicar The problem pertains to a gambling problem involving a random walk, where $a_n$ denotes the **first time** a player has **two dollars**. Every time the player flips a coin, he wins or loses a dollar. Therefore, you are right, it cannot happen **on n = 0**, and it cannot happen on ANY **odd flip**. Therefore, $a_2n$ is used, where only **even** flips are accounted, like $a_2$, and $a_4$ and so forth. The individual probabilities themselves are correct, but the question pertains to **what the probability is of winning on an even throw**, so the overall probability of **winning**.

Comment: @ViolettaBlejder So it seems that the probability is 1.